# Setting up Nginx configuration for an HTML landing page and React app

Tags: html, reactjs, ubuntu, nginx, nginx-config

I have a classic HTML one-page landing project and a React app running on localhost:3000. I want to open the index.html file on the base domain and open the React app on any other path. For example, somedomain.com should load the landing page, while somedomain.com/login should load the React app. How can I achieve this with my Nginx configuration?

Here's what I currently have in my Nginx configuration file:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    #...some ssl stuff

    server_name somedomain.com;

    index index.html index.htm;

    location = / {
        root /var/www/welcome; #landing files here including index.html
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
server {
    if ($host = somedomain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = somedomain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name somedomain.com;

    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

When I visit somedomain.com, I encounter a redirection loop, and the browser tries to open somedomain.com/index. How can I fix this issue?

Also it is Ok, if landing will be on somedomain.com/welcome, and react-app on any other path including base uri, but I didn't success when I had tried it - welcome was 404

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that Nginx processes location blocks in a specific order, and the first one that matches the given URI is used to process the request. In your configuration, the "location /" block matches every request because it's a catch-all location. As a result, even if a user requests the root of your domain, the request will be proxied to your React app, not served your static landing page.

Your use case can be resolved by setting a more specific rule to handle your React app routes while still keeping your landing page at the root of your domain.

The adjusted Nginx configuration would look like this:

```
server {
listen 443 ssl;
listen [::]:443 ssl;

#...some ssl stuff

server_name somedomain.com;

index index.html index.htm;

location = / {
    root /var/www/welcome; #landing files here including index.html
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location /app/ {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
}
server {
if ($host = somedomain.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot

if ($host = somedomain.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot

listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

server_name somedomain.com;

return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

This way, any route that starts with "app" (e.g., somedomain.com/app/login) will be redirected to your React app running on localhost:3000. You would need to adjust your React app to handle routes starting with /app/.

Comment: Is it possible to use /static/ or /welcome for the landing page instead of adjusting the React app? Also, regarding location, I have read that Nginx checks location rules from top to bottom and that =/ has more priority than just /.